# MVVM - How change backcolor for a single char in a datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I would the rows containing the **search value** (Search Name), show this value (in datagrid) with a different color.

See the pic below.

Some ideas about this  ?

[image]

Comment: You could use an *ItemControl*  to bind with each string and a *Horizontal StackPanel* as *ItemsPanel* for it. And a *TextBlock* as *DataTemplate* . Then you could have a *Converter*  for each *TextBlock.BackGroundColor* which would compare with the characters in the search box and accordingly set the backgroud color..

Comment: You might also want to checkout RichTextbox ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new control that extends a standard TextBlock, which uses a series of Run items to display the text, using the appropriate formatting.

```
public class HighlightTextBlock: TextBlock
{
    public string BaseText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BaseTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BaseTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BaseTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BaseText", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(null, UpdateDisplay));

    public string HighlightText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HighlightTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightText", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(null, UpdateDisplay));

    public Brush HighlightBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(HighlightBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(HighlightTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Orange, UpdateDisplay));

    public bool HighlightCaseSensitive
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HighlightCaseSensitiveProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightCaseSensitiveProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightCaseSensitiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightCaseSensitive", typeof(bool), typeof(HighlightTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(false, UpdateDisplay));

    private static void UpdateDisplay(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var hightlightTextBlock = sender as HighlightTextBlock;

        if (hightlightTextBlock == null)
            return;

        hightlightTextBlock.Inlines.Clear();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hightlightTextBlock.BaseText))
            return;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hightlightTextBlock.HighlightText))
        {
            hightlightTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(hightlightTextBlock.BaseText));
            return;
        }

        var textItems = Regex.Split(hightlightTextBlock.BaseText,
            "(" + hightlightTextBlock.HighlightText + ")",
            hightlightTextBlock.HighlightCaseSensitive ? RegexOptions.None : RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (var item in textItems)
        {
            var run = new Run(item);
            var highlight = hightlightTextBlock.HighlightCaseSensitive
                ? string.Compare(item, hightlightTextBlock.HighlightText, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) == 0
                : string.Compare(item, hightlightTextBlock.HighlightText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0;

            if (highlight)
                run.Background = hightlightTextBlock.HighlightBrush;

            hightlightTextBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
        }
    }
}
```

The brackets around the HighlightText value tells Regex.Split to include the matched text in the  returned list of items.

This control can then be used as part of an item template in your datagrid column definition. [See here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/) for an example of how to do that.

Comment: You can just substitute this new control anywhere you would normally use a standard TextBlock control. The only different is that rather than binding to the Text property for the displayed text, you bind to the BaseText property. Then bind to HighlightText to set the highlighted elements.